# Cannot set policy to a role in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-iam

I'm trying to set a policy that I configured to a role that I made in `aws`. The policy and role called test-policy and test-role were created from the `aws-console`. In the console I added the policy to the role in the permission policy section. However, if I try to print the policies associated with the test-role in `awscli2` with

```
aws iam list-role-policies --role-name test-role
```

I get the following:

```
{
    "PolicyNames": []
}
```

I then tried to attach the policy to the role via `awscli2` with the command

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name test-role --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:policy/test-policy-v1
```

And when I then again try to print the policies associated with the role I still get an empty list in `PolicyNames`, like the one above.

Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?